# How do i restrict the user entering "Space" in to the Textfield using Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Iam using this Formplugin engine for Validation

http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/

it has method such as "noSpecialCaracters" rules for the Validator .would that be Helpful.

Comment: You mean entering space any where or entering just space into the text?

Comment: What behaviour do you want? Trying entering a space into the field results in nothing happening? Or entering a space causes a validation to fail?

Comment: @cybernate: restricting in Entering Space in to the Textfield and space anywhere

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to prevent spaces from being entered when the space key is pressed the following does the job:

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type="text"]').keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 32) // 32 is the ASCII value for a space
            e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: what happen if you copy and paste?It is not working for copy and paste with space